# Using Index Match In excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Dim DateValues As Variant
Dim Shortfall As Variant
Dim Region As Variant
Dim Bucket As Variant

Dim Shortfall_rng As Range
Dim Region_rng As Range
Dim Bucket_rng As Range
Dim Datevalues_rng As Range

Dim estring As Variant

Dim StartCopying As Range


Set StartCopying = Worksheets("Asia_All").Range("O4")

Region = Worksheets("Asia_All").Range("O1").Value ' Value in cell O1 is "New York" (without Quotes)
Bucket = Worksheets("Asia_All").Range("O2").Value ' Value in cell O2 is "<!--1-->0 - 1" (without Quotes)
DateValues = Worksheets("Asia_All").Range("O3").Value ' Value in cell O3 is "2007-01-02" (without Quotes)



Set Shortfall_rng = Worksheets("Asia_All").Range("$B$2:$B$142411")
Set Bucket_rng = Worksheets("Asia_All").Range("$F$2:$F$142411")
Set Datevalues_rng = Worksheets("Asia_All").Range("J$2:$J$142411")
Set Region_rng = Worksheets("Asia_All").Range("$K$2:$K$142411")


estring = Evaluate("Index(" & Shortfall_rng.Address & ", Match(" & Bucket & Region & DateValues & ", " & Bucket_rng.Address & " & " & Region_rng.Address & "&" & Datevalues_rng.Address & ", 0))")

StartCopying.Value = estring
```

I am trying to use Index Match ,but I am getting #Value! error. Please note that it works absolutely fine if i manually enter the index match formula in the cell. This error appears only when i try to replicate it in excel vba.To give a brief,

**Bucket_rng column contains a coulmn of multiple values of**

```
 <!--1-->0 - 1
 <!--2-->1 - 2.5
 <!--3-->2.5 - 5
 <!--4-->5 - 10
 <!--5-->10+
```

**Shortfall_rng column contains a coulmn of multiple values like**

```
-4.69
-3.94
-53.94
150.18
-18.78
-9.98
-17.04
-41.32
0.0001
```

**Datevalues_rng column contains a coulmn of multiple values in yyyy-mm-dd format**

and

**Region_rng column contains a coulmn of multiple values like**

```
China
New York
Australia
Japan Continent
```

Comment: Are you sure you're entering it as an array formula in `estring`?

Comment: No. How would I do that @gareth ?

Comment: Try `Evaluate("{Index(" & Shortfall_rng.Address & ", Match(" & Bucket & Region & DateValues & ", " & Bucket_rng.Address & " & " & Region_rng.Address & "&" & Datevalues_rng.Address & ", 0))}")`. Notice the curly braces.

Comment: Can you include what the Excel function looks like if entered on the sheet?

Comment: @Gareth You can't add {} to the formula string in evaluate to coerce array-evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to enclose the string arguments in quotes inside the formula. It's easier, IMO, to use the cell addresses of the criteria cells too:

```
Dim ws                    As Worksheet
Dim DateValues            As Range
Dim Shortfall             As Range
Dim Region                As Range
Dim Bucket                As Range
Dim Shortfall_rng         As Range
Dim Region_rng            As Range
Dim Bucket_rng            As Range
Dim Datevalues_rng        As Range
Dim estring               As Variant
Dim StartCopying          As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Asia_All")

Set StartCopying = ws.Range("O4")

Set Region = ws.Range("O1")    ' Value in cell O1 is "New York" (without Quotes)
Set Bucket = ws.Range("O2")    ' Value in cell O2 is "<!--1-->0 - 1" (without Quotes)
Set DateValues = ws.Range("O3")    ' Value in cell O3 is "2007-01-02" (without Quotes)



Set Shortfall_rng = ws.Range("$B$2:$B$142411")
Set Bucket_rng = ws.Range("$F$2:$F$142411")
Set Datevalues_rng = ws.Range("J$2:$J$142411")
Set Region_rng = ws.Range("$K$2:$K$142411")


estring = ws.Evaluate("Index(" & Shortfall_rng.Address & ", Match(" & Bucket.Address & "&" & Region.Address & "&" & DateValues.Address & ", " & Bucket_rng.Address & " & " & Region_rng.Address & "&" & Datevalues_rng.Address & ", 0))")

StartCopying.Value = estring
```